# Are there ski/snowboard storage facilities in Whistler?

Tags: luggage-storage, skiing, whistler

I'm planning to travel to Whistler and I'd rather leave my skis there for a few days. Is there a place where I can store them for a fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store skis and snowboards in the Carlton Lodge in Whistler village for a fee of $10 per day. They can also accept your ski poles, but won't take helmets, boots and other equipment. There aren't any discounts for long term users, so this would be an expensive option for someone wanting to store their skis there all season.

Additionally there are personal lockers for holders of seasonal passes, but these have a two year waiting list at the moment so they're not accessible to the average skier.